# Get key value mapping from a JSON with random string appended to them

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON string as seen below.

**JSON**

```
{
  "wf.example.input1": "/path/to/file1",
  "wf.example.input3": [
    "/path/to/file3",
    "/path/to/file4"
  ]
}
```

I need a `list` output in below format.

```
name:"wf.example.input1", value:"/path/to/file1"
name:"wf.example.input3", value:"/path/to/file3"
name:"wf.example.input3", value:"/path/to/file4"
```

I know I can get all the keys using `jq 'keys'` and also all the values can be fetched using `jq 'flatten'`. But this doesn't give a list with all the mappings I need. So how do I get my desired output list mapping?

Comment: Hi, dont you wanna try write some code first...try use map function as well good for list transformations...then can help when you stuck, but from your code...is actually good like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert it to entries first, then you could build up your outputs for the keys and values.  For arrays of values, just go through all the values in the array, otherwise the value itself.

```
$ jq -r 'to_entries[] | "name:\(.key|tojson), value:\(.value|(arrays[]//.)|tojson)"' input.json
name:"wf.example.input1", value:"/path/to/file1"
name:"wf.example.input3", value:"/path/to/file3"
name:"wf.example.input3", value:"/path/to/file4"
```

Comment: p.s., The `arrays[] // .` part is effectively the same as: `if type == "array" then .[] else . end`